# Monodroid with Windows Azure Mobile Services - System.Runtime reference error

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

When I add this line:

```
private readonly MobileServiceClient _mobileServicesClient = new MobileServiceClient(AzureConfig.MobileServicesUri, AzureConfig.MobileServicesApplicationKey);
```

to my android project after installing the Azure Mobile Services component I get the following error:

```
The type `System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' (CS0012) (TellAt.Mobile.Droid)
```

That exact same line of code works fine in the iOS project.

I can't add a reference to System.Runtime - it's in mscorlib

Has anyone seen this before?

This happens in a brand new Xamarin Android app. Just add the Azure Mobile Services componenet and the following line to MAinActivity:

```
private readonly MobileServiceClient _mobileServicesClient = new MobileServiceClient(AzureConfig.MobileServicesUri, AzureConfig.MobileServicesApplicationKey);
```

And you will see the error.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got this working was to download the demo app from the Azure portal and refactor it to be the intended app.

Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a bug in the Xamarin Studio component integration, the demo app in the Azure portal was preconfigured to workaround the bug. Xamarin have now released a fix, so you should no longer see this issue.